# Closure compiler number getting undefined in advanced optimization

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I have the following line of code

```
frame = self.spriteData['backgroundps.png'];
self.bgBoard  = new gg.casino.game.sprite(self.spriteSheet, frame, 0, 0, frame.w, frame.h);
console.log(frame);
console.log(self.bgBoard.x + ' ' + self.bgBoard.y + ' ' + self.bgBoard.w + ' ' + self.bgBoard.h);
```

and gg.casino.game.sprite is defined as

```
gg.casino.game.sprite = function(sheet, frame, x, y, twidth, theight) {
    this.sheetRef                               =   sheet;
    this.frame                                  =   frame;
    this.x                                      =   x;  
    this.y                                      =   y;  
    this.w                                      =   twidth;
    this.h                                      =   theight;
    console.log(this.x + ' ' + this.y + ' ' + this.w + ' ' + this.h);
}
```

when compiling with simpleoptimization, everything works well and I get the following log:

```
0 0 800 480
(frame object)
0 0 800 480
```

but when I compile with advanced optimization, log shows

```
0 0 undefined undefined 
(frame object) - with correct values
0 0 undefined undefined
```

what could have gone wrong with this code?

**EDIT:**

added a log after `frame = self.spriteData['backgroundps.png'];`

```
console.log('ps ' + frame.w + '   ' + frame.h);
```

and it prints w and h as undefined !!!!!!

```
ps undefined undefined
```

where as `console.log(frame)` in next line prints the object with correct values

**Edit 2:**

more on self.spriteData:
I have a json file exported from texturepacker. It has an array of objects where each object is represented as

```
{
"filename": "backgroundps.png",
"frame": {"x":105,"y":304,"w":800,"h":480},
"rotated": false,
"trimmed": false,
"spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":800,"h":480},
"sourceSize": {"w":800,"h":480}
}
```

I loop through that json array and assign the values to `self.spriteData` as follows:

```
    var respData                            =   xhr.getResponseJson();
    self.spriteData                         =   {};
    for(var i = 0, len = respData.frames.length; i < len; i++) {
        self.spriteData[respData.frames[i].filename] = respData.frames[i].frame;
    }
```

so `frame` will having the following structure, which gets printed on console:

```
Object
  h: 480
  w: 800
  x: 105
  y: 304
```

so in advanced compilation, there is no problem if I print the `frame` as `console.log(frame)`. But when I try accessing its members `console.log(frame.h)` it prints as `undefined`. Just tried adding @expose comment to `var frame = {};`, hoping it wont get renamed, but didnt help.

**Edit:**
changed `frame` assignment as 
    frame.x                                     =   self.spriteData['backgroundps.png'].x;
    frame.y                                     =   self.spriteData['backgroundps.png'].y;
    frame.w                                     =   self.spriteData['backgroundps.png'].w;
    frame.h                                     =   self.spriteData['backgroundps.png'].h;

and declared `frame.w` and `frame.h` with comment `@type {number} (didnt do for x and y as the were working fine already).

Now console.log(frame) shows

```
Object
  a: undefined
  b: undefined
  x: 105
  y: 304
```

but why?

**EDIT (Solved)** :D :-)
I explicitly declared `frame`'s members as

```
/**
 * @type {number}
 * @expose
 */
frame.w                                     =   0;

/**
 * @type {number}
 * @expose
 */
frame.h                                     =   0;

/**
 * @type {number}
 * @expose
 */
frame.x                                     =   0;

/**
 * @type {number}
 * @expose
 */
frame.y                                     =   0;
```

and now it works :-)

thanks to Kayhr, Ross and Chad for you help. but now I wonder whose answer should I mark the right one?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly since you didn't post the complete code. Make sure to run the compiler with warning level VERBOSE as that will help point you to the problem. I can tell you right now that your sprite function needs an `/** @constructor */` annotation.

Comment: VERBOSE starts throwing errors for `console.log`.. have to define them as `externs` it seems.. ll do shortly. thx for the tip :-)

Comment: and I had `@constructor` and many other comments in my code, just removed those to post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the definition of self.spriteData['backgroundps.png']?

I would be willing to bet that the 'w' and 'h' keys of self.spriteData['backgroundps.png'] are defined with strings. If so, things will usually break when you access such properties with dot-syntax, because the compiler will leave strings untouched but optimize the names of properties written in dot-syntax.

For example:

```
  foo['bar'] => a['bar']
  foo.bar    => a.b
```

...where a and b are hypothetical compiler output tokens.

See: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#propnames

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce it. I have faked the missing code with simple objects to get your code running. The output is the same, doesn't matter if I use SIMPLE or ADVANCED optimization. I guess your problem is in the code which you did not mention here (Maybe in the definition of this spriteData stuff). Please give us a complete example and the exact compiler options you used.

Here is the code I'm compiling, maybe you can see a crucial difference to your REAL code:

```
// Faked code (The stuff you didn't include in the question):

var gg, self;
gg = {};
gg.casino = {};
gg.casino.game = {};
self = { spriteData: { 'backgroundps.png': { w: 800, h: 480 } } };

// Your code (unchanged):

gg.casino.game.sprite = function(sheet, frame, x, y, twidth, theight) {
    this.sheetRef                               =   sheet;
    this.frame                                  =   frame;
    this.x                                      =   x;  
    this.y                                      =   y;  
    this.w                                      =   twidth;
    this.h                                      =   theight;
    console.log(this.x + ' ' + this.y + ' ' + this.w + ' ' + this.h);
}

frame = self.spriteData['backgroundps.png'];
self.bgBoard  = new gg.casino.game.sprite(self.spriteSheet, frame, 0, 0,  frame.w, frame.h);
console.log(frame);
console.log(self.bgBoard.x + ' ' + self.bgBoard.y + ' ' + self.bgBoard.w +  ' ' + self.bgBoard.h);
```